# Is there an easy way to implement a jQuery plugin as part of a Drupal content node?

Tags: jquery, drupal, jquery-plugins, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have a jQuery plugin that I authored and I want it on only one node of my Drupal 6 web site. I have FTP and a Linux shell I can use for uploading files to the site, but the issue is actually attaching them to a node. Putting JavaScript in a node's Body can get pretty ugly, especially when the Body is presented in a WYSIWYG editor (haywire indentation,  WYSIWYG attempting to wrap all my <script> tags with <p> tags, etc)

Is there any sort of Drupal plugin or any kind of workaround to make this kind of integration easier?

Edit:

I've tried [Code Per Node](http://drupal.org/project/cpn), which is great for separating JavaScript from the Body, but I really need the option to link to separate JavaScript files (this plugin requires several support files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to make your own module that uses the plugin. That is the "Drupal" way to do it. You can also you drupal_add_js to attach scripts to the module. If it is only a specific node you need to attach this plugin to I would either make a if statement in the template looking for that node, kinda an ugly way to do it though.

Comment: I once tried to teach myself Drupal Module authoring. I found it to be a god-awful mess and eventually gave up on it.

Comment: Just because it is hard does not mean its not worth doing. You should learn how to author modules and Drupal will become infinitely more powerful for you

Comment: I tried. Twice, in fact. Trying to read the API documentation was so frustrating.

Comment: Also, I should mention that I'm going to want to do this for several different nodes, with several plugins I've authored, and I'd probably go nuts if I had to author a new module for each one.

Comment: Ok. I changed my mind. I'm going to try once more. I'm going to attempt to develop a Drupal plugin that adds "JavaScript URL" field[s] to node edit pages, and embeds those JavaScript files when that node loads. Probably I will also include a checkbox option to load a script file in the preview or only when the node is fully loaded. I'm sure I'll be asking many questions on SO as I go.

Answer (score 2):

The way I did this in a project was to add a CCK text field to the content type called "Additional Resources" that accepts multiple values. Then in the node I added multiple values in this field -- the paths to CSS and JS files I wanted to load on that node. Then, in my theme I added my own function called `themename_node_process_fields` in `template.php`. That function was the first thing executed in `node-content_type_name.tpl.php`. Among other things, it did this:

```
  // Loop through the additional resources and add them to the <head>.
  if (isset($node->field_additional_resources) && count($node->field_additional_resources) > 0) {
    foreach ($node->field_additional_resources as $resource) {
      if (strpos($resource['safe'], '.css') !== FALSE)
        drupal_add_css($resource['safe'], 'theme', 'all', FALSE);
      else if (strpos($resource['safe'], '.js') !== FALSE)
        drupal_add_js($resource['safe'], 'theme', 'header', FALSE, TRUE, FALSE);
    }
  }
```

Note that I have not thought through if there are any security considerations for this. I'm the only one that has access to that field, but if a malicious user were able to enter arbitrary text I'm not sure what could be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't looking for an administrative tool, you can use [`drupal_add_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js) function. It will insert the JavaScript file into the page at render time. However, this requires having the [PHP input filter](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/filter) activated.

```
...content...
<?php
  drupal_add_js('external_file.js', 'external');
?>
...more content...
```

From the link:

> **External:**
>   Add external JavaScript ('external'): Allows the inclusion of external JavaScript files that are not hosted on the local server. Note that these external JavaScript references do not get aggregated when preprocessing is on.

Comment: I can't turn on PHP Evaluator because I consider it to be a major security hole.

Comment: I only consider it a 'security hole' for untrusted users. I *only* allow it for site administrators. If you have evidence otherwise, please let me know.

Comment: I suppose it's PHP's shell_exec() function that really scares me.